# Wireshark decoding of BLE data

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark

I'm trying to decode the data received from a Bluetooth beacon :

I'm using Wireshark with an [nRF BLE Sniffer](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-sniffer-for-bluetooth-le).

I'm able to receive the data from my beacon :
[Data from the beacon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9i2M.png)

Now I'd like to decode the data from : Advertising Data → Manufacturer Specific → data.

The data sent by the beacon is :

| size | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 byte | analog data : Vcc |
| 2 bytes | analog data : Temperature |
| 6 bytes | I2C data |
| 4 bytes | counter : uptime |

All the data is in little endian format.

I need to cut the data into different sections to then do some basic multiplication on it to extract the information.

I've searched the Wireshark documentation, but haven't really found a way to do what I want.

**Is it possible to write a script to decode the data directly in Wireshark ?**
**If so, how could I do it ?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The magic word in this context is Wireshark [Dissector](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors).

With the help of a Wireshark dissector, that you can write in LUA, you can decode the part of the message that interests you and output it formatted.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll look further into it.